# How to fix the following error "Please specify environmental variable OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK to OpenCV Android SDK directory." in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to open a face recognizing app in android studio but it is showing me the following error "*** Please specify environmental variable OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK to OpenCV Android SDK directory."

How to fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Add an **system environment path** like the following example:

```
OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK=/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/OpenCV-android-sdk
//please use your own 'OpenCV-android-sdk' location
```

Comment: Can you please kindly give me step by step instructions